# C array struct initialisation and call

Tags: c, stm32cubeide

what is the right way to initialise and call the struct in C language STM32typedef

```
struct motor_struct {
    uint32_t yellow_clicks;
    uint32_t green_clicks;
    uint8_t pin;
    GPIO_TypeDef port;
    _Bool green_hall;
    _Bool yellow_hall;

} motors[4];



//motors(yellow_clicks) = {0,0,0,0}; - *compile without error but what is gone inside?*
motors[0].yellow_clicks  = 0; *- get an error*
```

Comment: You don't "call" a struct. Structs cannot be "called". They are not "callable".

Comment: When going to Stack Overflow to ask for help, never say "get an error". ***State. Precisely. What. Error.***

Comment: okay I mean how to correrctly change the value inside array of struct - last line of code

Comment: Of couerse, sorry: Error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token

Comment: You cannot run arbitrary code outside of a function.  Is this what your code actually looks like?

Comment: What you post and what you say you observe are at odds with each other. Nothing makes sense. So, post a [Minimal Compilable Reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which we can just compile with any C language compiler. The `stm32cubeide` is red-herring.  This is a question about `C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do something like:

```
motors[0].yellow_clicks  = 0;
```

inside a function. If you want to initialise your array of structures at compile-time, you'll need something like:

```
struct motor_struct {
    uint32_t yellow_clicks;
    uint32_t green_clicks;
    uint8_t pin;
    GPIO_TypeDef port;
    _Bool green_hall;
    _Bool yellow_hall;

} motors[4] = {
    {0, 0, 1, GPIOA, false, false}, // motors[0]
    {1, 1, 2, GPIOB, true, false},  // motors[1]
    {0, 1, 1, GPIOC, true, true},   // motors[2]
    {1, 2, 3, GPIOA, true, true}    // motors[3]
};
```

Of course using values that make sense for you.

Comment: clear. thaks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In order to *assign* values to a struct rather than *initialize* it at the point of declaration, you either need to set members one by one or use a temporary compound literal:

```
motors[i] = (struct motor_struct) { 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false };
```

---

Whether or not to use `typedef` for structs is a bit subjective, though in this case I think it would make the code more readable.

```c
typedef struct 
{
  uint32_t yellow_clicks;
  uint32_t green_clicks;
  GPIO_TypeDef port;
  uint8_t pin;
  _Bool green_hall;
  _Bool yellow_hall;
} motor_t;

motor_t motors[4] = { ... };
```

(Also note the struct padding optimization that I did - `GPIO_TypeDef` is likely some 32 bit pointer and so it should be declared above `pin` or you'll be waisting memory for nothing.)

---

Maybe also consider designated initializers:

```
motor_t motors[4] =
{
  [0] = { 
          .yellow_clicks = 123,  .green_clicks = 456,
          .port = PORTX,         .pin = 1,
          .green_hall = false,   .yellow_hall = false,
        },

  [1] = ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with **STM32CUBEIDE**, it's worth noting that when you declare a static global variable the startup code will zeroize the variable.

Zeroize means that the variable's memory will be filled with 0.

So in the following your `motors` array will be zeroized.

```
struct motor_struct {
    uint32_t yellow_clicks;
    uint32_t green_clicks;
    uint8_t pin;
    GPIO_TypeDef port;
    _Bool green_hall;
    _Bool yellow_hall;

};

static motor_struct motors[4];
```

https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2609-stm32cubeide-user-guide-stmicroelectronics.pdf